# aws codecommit repo folder override by git command run on local computer

Tags: git, gitignore, git-flow, git-log, aws-codecommit

There was a folder name called **profileimg** in the local computer and the AWS codecommit repository. That folder fills with images when a user uploads images. However, when I change some code in the local computer repo and git push into remote repo ( AWS codecommit repo ), **profileimg** folder override with empty data and images are being disappeared. This was a Laravel 8 project hosted in the AWS beanstalk environment.

What I tried so far in the local git repo:

- $ git rm -r --cached public/images/profileimg/*
- $ git update-index --assume-unchanged public/images/profileimg/*

**Folder structure:**

- public

  - images

    - profileimg
- .gitignore

**.gitignore**

```
#exclude everything
public/images/profileimg/*
public/images/profileVerifyDoc/*

#exception
!public/images/profileimg/.gitkeep
!public/images/profileVerifyDoc/.gitkeep
```

[image]

[image]

Moreover, I created .ebignore file in the AWS codecommit repo. The local computer also has .gitignore file. Any suggestion, please.

Comment: Can you check gitlog? is it possible to reset HEAD the commit, how much code changes you will loose with reset HEAD, will that be a affordable option?

Comment: git log includes a few commits but the issue is I need to includes an empty folder named "profileimg" in the first commit and then after I don't need that folder in local computer.

Comment: instead of that create two untracked folders keeping the folder name in gitignore, so both folder will be unmapped and work independently.

Comment: current .gitignore file has "profileimg" folder path. how do I do that?

Comment: okay another way you can do it keep the folder and escape the ocntains/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

profileimg folder has created to store user images that are changing over time. When I added new changes to the code base and git push them to the AWS Beanstalk environment, the existing files and folders getting replace with the new changes. The solution is to create an S 3 bucket or save the images in a separate location.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.concepts.design.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty file called .gitkeep inside profileimg, then in your .gitignore file write:

```
# exclude everything
profileimg/*

# exception to the rule
!profileimg/.gitkeep
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This didn't work either.  Still, override files in remote directory after git push. Is there something to do with AWS codecommit and codepipe? every solution didn't work.

Comment: @aseladaskon No, it does not seem to be issue with AWS codecommit. Can you share screenshot of your folder structure, where you have profileimg/ and .gitignore filw?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @aseladaskon can you post content of your .gitignore file?

Comment: @aseladaskon now you should commit your untracked files and then see if new local files inside profilimg are going or only folder and.gitkeep is going.

Comment: I did this process several times but what happens was the folder in the remote repo has deleted. The local computer folder was there.

Comment: @aseladaskon I will try to recreate this and update you on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I created a new local folder and added all the Laravel app files. Then I did as follow. 1> git init  2> git remote add origin url xxxxxxx  3> git add .  4> git commit -m 'initial commit'   5> git push -u origin master   6> git rm -r  --cached public/images/profileimg   7> git commit -m 'message'  8> created a .gitignore file in the root directory  9> added the path to the folder  /public/images/profileimg/

Comment: @aseladaskon This is work around, you are adding and removing, why not just take exactly what you want to take? That is why we will try with .gitignore and .gitkeep

Comment: I'm okay with either way. keep the folder and files in local but untracked or delete them from the local. The issue is when I untracked using git rm -r --cached public/images/profileimg  folder goes to the untracked list and after I pushing the changes to the remote, profileimg folder has deleted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763749/elastic-beanstalk-prevent-files-overwriting   I think this might be the issue.

Comment: @aseladaskon  yes it can be the issue.

Comment: @aseladaskon in normal scenario if you will create a folder and do not want to push the content, this solution is working.

Comment: I specifically ask about something to do with codecommit and codepipeline process in AWS. That was the issue. Each time I deploy the app, beanstalk replace the entire app with the new version. Thanks for your reply.